# Change background color of Select item in navigation of PhpStorm IDE

Tags: phpstorm

As you can see in the image, how could I change the background color of the selected text in navigation bar and make it lighter ?

[image]

Comment: I doubt. You are using custom GUI Theme .. and that does not have customization interface. Better ask plugin/theme authors.

Comment: what's the instruction for default theme ?

Comment: No instructions -- GUI Theme (also known as Look and Feel in Java Swing apps) do not have direct customisation, at very least not in this IDE. Possibly it can be achieved by coding a plugin that does such changes in runtime (like the one you are using) ... but there is no GUI for such elements in this IDE.